# Include an Apex VisualForce Page in New Task Form

Tags: apex, tasks, visualforce, form

I must add 5 fields on the standard task form wich will modifiy the linked account fields when a specific task is saved.

How can i do that ? Can we just include a VF page in the standard form and use a trigger to save the data ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: create custom field and then use trigger or if you want to store field value temporarily then use VF page.

Comment: If you embed a visualforce page in a standard page layout, it is treated as a separate form. You would probably want to directly include your custom fields on the page layout.

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks, yes it's the two solutions i'd seen before...

Answer (score 2):

No need for code.

1. Create custom fields on task
2. Create a process on task
3. Use the process to update the related account

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can override the New Task button and include VF page instead of standard task form.In task trigger you can check whether task is associated with account and if yes then you can update the account.

Comment: Then, if i use a VF page to override the standard task form, is there a way to include in my new VF page the standard task form?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to include Standard form in your custom VF page?